# Efficient way to work with List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

Please be aware this is a false issue. I asked it because when I tried to use Iterator,  my IntelliJ keeps alarming on "Iterator" saying Iterator could not have type parameters, which is not true.

Somehow, my IntelliJ seems to showing the javadoc of java 1.4. I am still trying to fix it. Thanks.

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I worked on a java program where an api returns a List.

My way of handling this is:

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(apiThatReturnsAList);
for (SomeObject someObject : arrayList) {
    ...
}
```

My code reviewer suggests this might be a less efficient way to deal with it because it copies the data. He recommended I use Iterator. But I find the code would be like this:

```
Iterator iterator = apiThatReturnsAList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject)iterator.next();
}
```

There is ugly casting here which we don't want to see because it is not safe.

So, is there an efficient way to deal with this api and not copying the data?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use generics.

Comment: Why do you think you need to copy the `List`? Any why are you using a **raw type** `Iterator`. And why are you referencing an `ArrayList` directly. If I were your reviewer I would have quite a few comments about this mess.

Comment: And what is wrong with simply iterating the returned list in the first place?

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid a copying, you can use `foreach` for `apiThatReturnsAList`

```
for (SomeObject someObject : apiThatReturnsAList) {
    ...
}
```

In fact, `foreach` does the same work with iterator under the hood [JLS 14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Answer (score 4):

Just parameterize your iterator with the expected class:

```
Iterator<SomeObject> iterator = apiThatReturnsAList.iterator();
```

and you will get a `SomeObject` instance when you call `next()` :

```
Iterator<SomeObject> iterator = apiThatReturnsAList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SomeObject someObject = iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: Iterator has type parameter?

Comment: @BoYuan oh come on. Really? [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: Actually, I did this before asking this question. I tracked and don't see this in my library. And IntelliJ keeps telling me Iterator does not have type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-each to print the contents of the elements in the `apiThatReturnsList`:

```
for (SomeObject element : apiThatReturnsList) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

There's no need to copy the list into another list.